# Octave: Plotyy log files from geothermal heat pump (import/plot datetime)

Tags: csv, datetime, plot, octave

I'm trying to plot values from my geothermal heat pump log files to analyse it's performance. I tried with excel but it was to slow and not possible to get the plot type I wanted so I'm trying Octave instead. I have absolutely no experience with octave so please forgive my incompetence!

I've processed the .log files with open office calc to get into a decent delimited format. The first column is datetime with the format MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS, in total there is 21 columns (but I only need 5) and one header line with a label, coma delimiter is '.' and delimiter is ','. The file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K_czefz-Wz4HPdvc7YqIqIupPwMi8a7r) and the first 7 columns look like this:

```
02/19/2018 23:07:00,-0.7,47.5,42,47.3,52.1,1.5
```

I'm currently trying to plot this with demonstration 3 plotyy from [here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/plotyy.html). Column 2, 3, 5 and 8 imports correctly so I'm figuring it's a problem with the datetime column 1. How can I get Octave to import column 1 correctly and use it as x axis in this plot?:

```
 data=csvread('heatpump.csv');  
 clf;
 hold on
 t=data(:,1); 
 x=data(:,3); 
 y=data(:,5); 
 z=data(:,2); 
 o=data(:,8); 
 [hax, h1, h2] = plotyy (t, x, t, y);
 [~, h3, h4] = plotyy (t, z, t, o);
 set ([h3, h4], "linestyle", "--");
 xlabel (hax(1), "Time");
 title (hax(2), 'Heat pump analysis');
 ylabel (hax(1), "Radiator and hot water temp");
 ylabel (hax(2), "Outdoor temp and brine out");
```

Comment: The help for csvread says: "Note: only CSV files containing numeric data can be read." -> use csv2cell from the io package instead. You can then convert the string to a serial date with `t = datenum(d(2:end,1), "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many ways. Here I show you how to read the csv using `csv2cell` from the io package. I've tried to modify your existing code as less as sane. The first columns is used verbatim (well, I inserted a linebreak) to the plot. There is also a commented version which actually does the conversion and you could then use `datetick`. Btw, If you add google drive links it would be cool if you add direct links so someone can easily grab the csv or insert the url in the code as I've done, see below.

```
set (0, "defaultlinelinewidth", 2);
url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1K_czefz-Wz4HPdvc7YqIqIupPwMi8a7r";
fn = "heatpump.csv";

if (! exist (fn, "file"))
  urlwrite (url, fn);
endif

pkg load io
d = csv2cell (fn);

# convert to serial date
# (but you don't have if you want to keep the old format)
#t = datenum (d(2:end,1), "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS");

data = cell2mat (d(2:end,2:end)); 
clf;
hold on
t = 1:rows (data);

# Attention: the date/time column time was removed above, so the indizes are shifted
x = data(:,2); 
y = data(:,4); 
z = data(:,1); 
o = data(:,7); 
[hax, h1, h2] = plotyy (t, x, t, y);
[hax2, h3, h4] = plotyy (t, z, t, o);
grid on

#set ([h3, h4], "linestyle", "--");
xlabel (hax(1), "Time");
title (hax(2), 'Heat pump analysis');
ylabel (hax(1), "Radiator and hot water temp");
ylabel (hax(2), "Outdoor temp and brine out");

# use date as xtick

# extract them
date_time = d (get(hax2(1), "xtick"), 1);

# break them after the date part
date_time = strrep (date_time, " ", "\n");

# feed them back
set (hax, "xticklabel", date_time)
set (hax2, "xticklabel", date_time)

print ("-S1200,1000", "-F:10", "out.png")
```

[image: output]

Comment: Incredible and also easy to understand! Running out of ways to say thank you here. There is one little problem for me, the x-axis is 0-1300 and the dotted values (z and y) should stay around +-10 (right y scale bar 30 to 65 above. Se screenshot here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K_czefz-Wz4HPdvc7YqIqIupPwMi8a7r

Comment: I don't speak this language so I don't know what z = Utetemp BT1(40004) and y = Varmvatten laddning BT6(40014) means. You should also use selfspeaking variable names in your scripts

Comment: Sorry, I miss typed the last comment. The dotted plots should be h3(z=column 2) and h4 (o=column 8). z = Utetemp and o = köldbärare ut and those columns have a range from -10 to about +10, not 30 to 65 like the current right y axis states. The z and y (h1 and h2) has a range around  40 +/- 10. And also the time (x) axis dosen't look like your example above, it just starts with 0 and end on 1300. Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qmzMhHVZkevMzq4X0jSeOk0cH2MXiFsB

Comment: when removing the # before datenum no plot is produced and I get this error: "subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
error: called from
    test at line 39" and line 39 is  "date_time = d (get(hax2(1), "xtick"), 1);"

Comment: of course the datenum don't work out of the box, you have to add datetick and so on yourself. Without veven knowing which Octave version you are using it's hard to tell why you sed 0:1300

Comment: Octave 4.0.3 64bit for mac with qt 4.8.7. But I have access to a more recent version att work if it matters. I'm more concerned that z and o isn't getting data from column 2 and 8 when thats what the code reads.

Comment: since `data = cell2mat (d(2:end,2:end));` the date/time column is removed and all indices should be lowered by one. I'll fix this in the code

Comment: I see, -1 on all column calls worked like a charm! Thank you so much for helping me out. The heat pump is not working like it should and I need to understand what wrong better then I do now before I call customer service. Would there be a way to also add a legend with help of the extracted header d? And is there a way to set the right y axis maximum to +10 while the left y axis scale remains like it is?

Comment: For me, this would have made perfect sense, but unfortunately two of the plots is out of the picture if I add the following code. Is it impossible to set differents limits?:

set(hax(1),'YLim',[0 70]);
set(hax(2),'YLim',[-10 10]);

Comment: you have to set the limits on hax AND hax2. and of course if would be possible to add a `legend`

Comment: You're the best. The datenum worked out of the box at work where I'm running Octave 4.2.1. Now I'm just trying to set xtick so that I get more time values than the current 4. I'm trying "set (gca, "xtick", 1:600:8432);" but it's just plotting a lot of dates above the four mentioned above. Could you hint on how to control the xtick?

Comment: the problem is, that you have to plotyy in one figure so you have to change xtick on both (hax and hax2) (don't use gca), btw, there ia a matlab and octave chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/chatlab-and-talktave

Comment: Thanks  for the chat, didn't know there was one. I've tried skipping GCA and using "set (hax, "xtick", 1:600:8432);" and "set (hax2, "xtick", 1:600:8432);" but now the time scale "starts over" in the middle of the plot. Was gonna ask in the chat but didn't know how to bring them up to speed with you previous code..

Comment: @johlund Have you solved this in the meanwhile or do you still need help?

Comment: Still haven't understod how to control the time axis.